# How to recover private key from ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am stuck while using a `VM_instance` on GC. I was granted to join an existing project and managed to create a VM Instance (let s call it `myInstance`).

GCP has created for me **automatically** `user_first` as user for `myInstance` => `user_first@myInstance`. The fact is that for some reason after some reboots, I was no more able to join this instance through ssh.

After some checking on forums, I set `Gcloud compute config-ssh` afterward... And looks like VM had created a new user `user_first_gmail_com`...  => `user_first_gmail_com@myInstance`.

The question here is how to get back to the initial user `user_first`?

Otherwise how could I get the password for `user_first` so that I could `sudo` as is and not as `user_first_gmail_com`?

Thank you for your precious help :-)

Answer (score 1):

By defeault GCP's VM use SSH keys to authenticate users instead of passwords. So in essence - user gets an SSH key and can't login with password. Hence - you can't recover it.

Fastest and most proven method is to use a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) that will actually add a user & password to that VM:

```
echo "username:password" | chpasswd
```

[More on adding users here](https://serverfault.com/questions/868092/how-do-i-create-a-user-with-a-password-in-one-line-in-bash-on-redhat).

Then [enable serial console interaction](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console#enabling_interactive_access_on_the_serial_console) and login with the given credentials.

After that go into the user's home directortory; `/home/usershomedir/.ssh/ and you will find all the keys in` authirized_keys` file.

This will allow you to read the keys and possibly get access to the instance the regular way.

But there are many reasons why you're getting `Permission denied (publickey). ERROR:`.
Check if the main disk isn't full. If that is so there's no place for the system features to work correctly (such as logging in users).

I'm pasting [my own reply](https://serverfault.com/a/1045717/545593) from another similar issue:

> If you have [OS login enabled](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) you control access to your VM's by [granting appropriate roles in the IAM](https://serverfault.com/questions/868092/how-do-i-create-a-user-with-a-password-in-one-line-in-bash-on-redhat). Most convinient & centralised way to grant SSH acces to your OS enabled VM's would be to create a dedicated service account and [grant it SSH access](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#service_account).
>
> It's good to try to [update your SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/os-login/ssh-keys/update): `gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys update`
>
> If you have OS login disabled (default setting, unless your organisation forces it enabled) then you can try [update your SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/config-ssh) with `gcloud compute config-ssh`.

If you're still unable to connect you can have a look at the general [SSH troubleshhoting documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/config-ssh).

And [one more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63574039/12257250) that may give you a hint how to get to your VM.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the change to the SSH config file by this command, run:

```
gcloud compute config-ssh --remove
```

Please refer this doc[1] for additional information.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/config-ssh

If you still facing the same issue (or) I may have misunderstood your question means kindly let me know? I will try to provide a better solution to solve your issue.

Comment: It has not actually resolved our issue as I may have removed manually keys in ~/.ssh while debugging the ssh issue.... Do you know by chance if there is a mean to retrieve the password of the former instance "user_instance" as it could resolve my issue. Actually I am a sudoer as  newly "user_instance_gmail_com" thus  I can change user with the former but cannot no more install stuffs without having password...

Comment: If you lost your private key means you can re-generate by using this command: `gcloud compute ssh [instance_name]`.

Comment: Hi Vishal, sorry to come back later... It did not work either. The bottom line is how to get the password for a "user" created by default by GCP ? so as to be able to sudo as this "user" if we get granted as root for instance.

Comment: Please provide some error messages you're getting and I can try to help you.

Comment: After  : gcloud compute ssh user_first@35.233.x.xx, we got the error  : Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the real issue consist in how to get the passwd for the user set/created by default by GCP after having created a VM instance and ssh it.
At some time we assume we will need a passwd for this "user" for countless reasons...